# No output is displayed in my Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

> I am a beginner at javascript and i am stuck with this piece of code. Syntactically the code seems to have no error but when it is executed there is no output, both in the webpage and the console. Hence I am confused and am unable to understand where the error lies.

```js
function SubMit() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("user").value;
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = userName;

  var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;

  var lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;

  var eMail = document.getElementById("email").value;

  var p1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;

  var p2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;

  console.log(userName);
  console.log(fName);
  console.log(lName);
  console.log(eMail);
  console.log(p1);
  console.log(p2);
}

function click() {
  document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD";
  console.log("hello world");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="user" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass1" required>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="pass2" required>
  <button type="submit" onclick="SubMit()">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
<output id="out"></output>

<button type="button" onclick="click()">click me</button>
<p id="c"></p>
```

Comment: The problem with the `c` button is most likely the name of the function, just rename it from `click` to something like `btnClick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click() is already defined as a javascript method

```js
function SubMit() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("user").value;
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = userName;

  var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;

  var lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;

  var eMail = document.getElementById("email").value;

  var p1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;

  var p2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;

  console.log(userName);
  console.log(fName);
  console.log(lName);
  console.log(eMail);
  console.log(p1);
  console.log(p2);
}

function myClick() {
  document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD";
  console.log("hello world");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="user" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass1" required>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="pass2" required>
  <button type="submit" onclick="SubMit()">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
<output id="out"></output>

<button type="button" onclick="myClick()">click me</button>
<p id="c"></p>
```

Comment: Might be good to explain *where* it's defined, e.g., in `onclick` you're already scoped to the element, and HTMLElements have a `click` method.

Answer (score 1):

Change output tag with div tag as.

```
<div id="out"></div>
```

rename click() to any other name. click() is predefined js function and you have to override the function before using it preventing the click event.